# Read in matrix from file, make edgelist, and write edgelist with values to file python

Tags: python, matrix

1. List item

read a matrix from a file into Python (that matrix has no headers/row names)
convert it to an edgelist
write the edgelist with values to file

- List item

input.txt

```
name  a  b  c  d 
  a   0  0  0  0
  b   0  0  1  1
  c   0  1  0  1
  d   0  1  1  0
```

ouptput.txt

```
a b 0
a c 0
a d 0
b c 1
b d 1
c d 1
```

enter code here

```
adj=open("input.txt","r+")
  for row,line in enumerate(adj.split('\n')):
     for col,val in enumerate(line.split(' ')):
       if val =="1" or val =="0":
          print  row, col, val
adj.close()
```

Comment: 1.read a matrix from a file into Python (that matrix has  headers/row names)
2.convert it to an edgelist
3.write the edgelist with value to file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should open both files together using `with` statement , so that the statement itself handles closing the files for you.

And then this is wrong - `adj.split('\n')` , file do not have split, you can directly iterable over it, removing the `.split('\n')` part. And then instead of print, write to the other file. Example -

```
with open("input.txt","r") as adj, open('output.txt','w') as out:
    header = next(adj).split()
    for line in adj:
        yval = line.split()[0]
        for col,val in enumerate(line.split()):
            if (val =="1" or val =="0") and col != 0:
                out.write("{0} {1} {2}\n".format(yval, header[col], val))
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> with open("input.txt","r") as adj, open('output.txt','w') as out:
...     header = next(adj).split()
...     for line in adj:
...         yval = line.split()[0]
...         for col,val in enumerate(line.split()):
...             if (val =="1" or val =="0") and col != 0:
...                 out.write("{0} {1} {2}\n".format(yval, header[col], val))
```

Output in `Output,txt` -

```
a a 0
a b 0
a c 0
a d 0
b a 0
b b 0
b c 1
b d 1
c a 0
c b 1
c c 0
c d 1
d a 0
d b 1
d c 1
d d 0
```

Comment: your exzmple can solve py question,but not the better way.if the head line and column with “str”,e,g:head line :Event   "PRDM2,:chr1-14127643-14355202_AMPLIFICATION"   "SDC3,:chr1-31372734-31372788_AMPLIFICATION"
first colum:TCGA-04-1530
                  TCGA-13-1496

Comment: What do you mean? do you want to consider head line and first column for the edgelist?

Comment: yes,i want to consider head line and first column for the edgelist

Comment: b  0

c  0

d  0

b  0

c  0

d  1

b  0

c  1

d  0

b  0

c  1

d  1

Comment: sorry, had the x/y values opposite, check now. Added example/demo output for me.

Comment: thanks it works,can you share your mail or skype,if i have other problem about python will ask you?

Comment: You can always come ask here, I would surely reply.